# How do I share settings data between two macOS apps?

Tags: swift, macos

I have two macOS apps, A and B, where A is a "helper app" that sits in the menu bar and launches B. B should not be launched independently of A, so it resides in A's app bundle (in A's Resources directory).

I want B to perform a sequence of actions based on the settings defined in A. I cannot use command line arguments, as the apps are sandboxed. Using a settings file in A's Resource directory seems a bit clunky. I'm not familiar with XPC (I'm completely new to macOS dev), but it seems overkill for just getting a few strings on launch.

Is there another method that is more suitable for sharing data like this?

Comment: It sounds like [AppGroups](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-app-groups) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, that does look like the right approach for this scenario!

Comment: If you want "real time" communication between the two, then the predominant inter-process communication (IPC) technology on MacOS is called XPC. I'd strongly recommend https://github.com/trilemma-dev/SecureXPC